# Trouble instantiating a class

Tags: java

I've some trouble compiling this program. The error message I get says that "Forside" abstract cannot be instantiated". I have troubles fixing this.

Here's my code and thank you in advance.

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;

  public abstract class Forside implements ActionListener {

     private Forside() {

   JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("BasisBaren - Sudentersamfundet");


        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        jfrm.setSize(1500, 1000);

        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jbtnOel = new JButton("OEL");
        JButton jbtnAndreDrikkevarer = new JButton("Andre Drikkevarer");
        JButton jbtnTender = new JButton("Tender");
        JButton jbtnSnacks = new JButton("Snacks");


        jbtnOel.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnAndreDrikkevarer.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnTender.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnSnacks.addActionListener(this);


        jfrm.add(jbtnOel);
        jfrm.add(jbtnAndreDrikkevarer);
        jfrm.add(jbtnTender);
        jfrm.add(jbtnSnacks);

    }

 public static void main (String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater (Forside::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. You need a concrete class for instantiation to happen which can be done by removing the `abstract` modifier or creating a new subclass.

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

Read up the documentations [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `abstract` modifier from the class declaration in order to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

The message says it all: *you can't instantiate an abstract class*. You **either** have to **remove** the `abstract` from your class definition or you have to create another class to **extend your abstract class** in case you feel you will need different versions of your "Forside" class:

```
public class ConcreteForside extends Forside {

}
```

Comment: I tried adding the code and it compiled successfully, but it closed down immediately. 

  @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }
}

Comment: What do you mean with "closed down immediately"? You understood that you should only follow the second path (extend the abstract class) if you really need to have "Forside" as an abstract (non-instantiable) class?

Comment: I tried extending the class, but I managed to get more errors. It didn't solve any bugs..

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. Did you also try Samuel's answer and remove the `abstract` from your class?